# Socket.io room empty event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have online file editing application using socket.io. Users join a room that is related with particular file they want to work with. I don't want use file system every time user changes something, so file is cached in memory, but when file is not used anymore I would like to save it on the disk.
As far as I know users are removed from a room as soon as they are disconnected. Is there a way to subscribe on "room empty" event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {})
```

and count the number of open connections.

- Torben

Comment: Thanks. Probably I will make it as you suggest. I thought there is more elegant way to observe rooms.

Comment: Having an event for "room empty" is syntactic sugar - not having such an event is more elegant in my view :-)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. All this tells you is when a socket is disconnected, it does not tell you if one or more of the rooms this socket is a member of is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you're managing rooms somehow, then you can use this:

```
io.sockets.clients('room name');
```

And this returns socket instances of all client in a room. If the length of this list is 0 then it means file is no longer used by any client and is ready to be saved. Hope this will work!